# Adjust Excel cell width to fit text with xlwt

Tags: python, excel, xlwt, file-writing

I'm making a Python application that writes to Excel files. My problem is that, when I write data to a cell that is longer than the with of the cell, excel 'hides' it.

I was wondering how is it possible  that the cell automatically adjust its width according to the length of the text? I'm using the xlwt package to write Excel files.